# How can I use Google Sheets custom function to detect if a row was added?

Tags: google-sheets, triggers

I am trying figure out how to write a function that can detect if a new row was added by the user. If a row was added I want that row to automatically fill in a green color.

Comment: How do I implement this? @|'-'|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Google's documentation for the Change trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change).  (Note that the end user needs to grant permission for the script to run)

```
function onChange(e){
   if(e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW'){ /* do stuff */ }
}
```

Comment: The "change event" trigger is not a "simple trigger", so naming the function `onChange` (which mimics the simple trigger bindings for `onOpen` and `onEdit`) is not recommended.

Comment: @tehhowch: Great point.  Thank you.  (Is there a recommended resource for naming conventions?)